# Database relationship between entities

Tags: database, relationship, entity-relationship

I have a question which I feel might be simple. I am relatively new to databases. I was looking at this conceptual ERD and saw these relationships between Seat -> Musical_Performance & Customer -> Booking
Customer has 1..6 -> 0..* AND Musical_Performance 1..1 -> 100..1500
What relationships are these. Is Customer to Booking a many to many relationship and is
Musical_Performance to Seat a one to many?
Really confused about this and would appreciate anyone helping me out

[image]

Comment: does this help? https://www.guru99.com/er-diagram-tutorial-dbms.html

Comment: Weak title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Thanks for linking that @OldProgrammer. It's a little tricky, I don't understand the relationships when it is written like it is there. We are being taught the relationships in numbers as in 100..500.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. `Musical_Performance` is one to many with `seat`. For each Musical Performance you can have multiple seats (100 to 1500).

`Customer` to `Booking` is many to many, each customer can have multiple booking (0 or more) but each booking can be connected just to 1-6 specific customers. This is probably comes to represent that you can book something for a family for example so one booking will have all of the family members customers.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! Really appreciate it. So a many relationship does not need  a * symbol to define it? the symbol is just a placeholder just say there can be many no matter how many? if that makes sense

Comment: Booking to Seat will then also be a one to many?

Comment: @ASH yes, Booking to seat will be one to many. And as you said * says it can be as many as you want.

Answer (score 0):

WHat you have, looks like a Chen style ERD. These numbers can describe a minimum, or an optional:mandatory relationship. In this specific case, I'm not sure what they are relating to, but dig in:

https://www.smartdraw.com/entity-relationship-diagram/

and

https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/er-diagrams

and

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-mysql/0596008643/ch04s03.html

for more information.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I will have a look!